# How to save and load CvSVMParams in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

Is there any built-in method to save and load CvSVMParams in opencv?

If it's important I'm using opencv 2.4.

Comment: Have you tried [save](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel-save)?

Comment: @Miki it's for model not for parameters.

Comment: the model doesn't contains also the parameters?

Comment: @Miki I think not all, for example number of iteration and epsilon.

Comment: ok, I can't try right now, so you must be correct :D

Comment: @Miki I was wrong this data also saved in model file like  `term_criteria: { epsilon:1.1920928955078125e-07, iterations:1000 }`

Comment: seems you can write the answer then :D